# Stuck when zooming image with slider in WPF

Tags: wpf

I recently build some of WPF application for displaying image. This application display an image using canvas. And that canvas placed inside a ScrollView. I need to zoom out and zoom in the image using value from  slider. When the scale of image less than the width of ScrollView, everything works fine. But when the scale of image approach the ScrollView width or more then WPF Application get stuck and there is an error displaying in the output console like "The thread 0x214c has exited with code 259 (0x103)".

This is my code to zooming the image:

```
private void Zoom(double m)
    {
        if (this.img != null && this.img.Source != null)
        {
            double temp = defaultScale * m;

            double ww = img.Source.Width * temp;
            double hh = img.Source.Height * temp;

            drawingCanvas.Width = ww;
            drawingCanvas.Height = hh;

            this.img.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(temp, temp); 
        }
    }
```

And the structure of XAML code is

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="DragNDrop2.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="448" Width="693">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="DRAW" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.76,0.455" Height="26" Click="DrawImage" Margin="98,0,0,0"/>
        <Button Content="OPEN" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="93" Height="26" Click="OpenImage"/>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,31,0,0">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="canvasViewer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="377" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="675" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <Canvas x:Name="drawingCanvas" Height="258" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="414" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>
        <Slider x:Name="scaleSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="211,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="296" ValueChanged="scaleSlider_ValueChanged" Value="5.0" TickFrequency="0.01"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Until now I can't figured out why this happen. I tried everything but I still don't understand the reason for that error emerge.

I post some video on youtube to visualize this 
https://youtu.be/CwLeYHMrW30

And the complete source code I publish on google drive:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1irLqfPwjq0eVYyQnVvNC1qYUE/view?usp=sharing

I'm very appreciate if there solution for this problem (or explanation).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check this solution:

```
<Slider HorizontalAlignment="Left" Minimum="x" Maximum="y" x:Name="ZoomInput"  ValueChanged="ZoomInput_OnValueChanged"/>

private void ZoomInput_OnValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    ImageScaleTransform.ScaleX = e.NewValue;
    ImageScaleTransform.ScaleY = e.NewValue;
    CanvasScaleTransform.ScaleX = e.NewValue;
    CanvasScaleTransform.ScaleY = e.NewValue;
    SetImagePosiotionInBounds();
}
```

and for canvas and image add ScaleTransform:

```
<Canvas x:Name="drawingCanvas" Height="258" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="414">
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform x:Name="CanvasScaleTransform"></ScaleTransform>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
</Canvas>
```

It works for me.